# How to extract all string that match a certain pattern and explode as rows in SQL

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table like

```
memberid  content
1         hello @abc
2         I'm happy @sunny @rainy
```

My expected output

```
memberid  text_after_@
1         abc
2         sunny 
2         rainy
```

[SQLFidle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c9a12/1)

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows

Answer (score 0):

```
        SELECT memberid, 
          Min(Substr(content, 
         INSTR(CONTENT, 
          '@') 
        , Length(content))) over
         (Partition by Substr(content, 
         INSTR(CONTENT, 
          '@'), Length(content)) order by 
           memberid) 

        from 
        table
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be an ugly way of doing it, but works.

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE(memberid,c1,n,cnt) AS (
SELECT MEMBERID,
       SUBSTRING(content FROM (LOCATE('@',content))+1) as c1,
       1 as n,
       LENGTH(content)-LENGTH(REPLACE(content ,'@','')) as cnt FROM TEST
union all
SELECT MEMBERID,
       SUBSTRING(c1 FROM (LOCATE('@',c1))+1),
       n+1,
       cnt FROM cte
where n<cnt
)
SELECT DISTINCT MEMBERID,
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(c1, ' ', 1) AS TEXT_AFTER 
FROM CTE 
ORDER BY MEMBERID
```

[**CHECK DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a6600951f5afa27f4aaed455efbb9d40)